# Trecho HTML como parâmetro de uma função javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho pouco conhecimento de javascript, como posso fazer para passar um código de incorporação de algum vídeo em uma função como uma string?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="exibirVideo('CODIGO DE EMBED AQUI')">
```

Estou tendo problemas pois não consigo passar a embed do vídeo como string, o que acaba encerrando a tag `<a>` prematuramente com alguma das `>` internas da embed

Answer (score 1):

Se você definir o callback de "click" da âncora em `<script*src=*>*</script>` você nunca terá que enfrentar problemas de script-inline.

O seu problema deve ser relacionado à aspas, é possível resolver utilizando aspas *(")* se no atributo da âncora foram utilizados apóstrofos *(')* para representar um valor, ou vice-versa.

Se você quiser representar uma aspa ou apóstrofo em uma string no JavaScript você pode escapá-la com \, por exemplo: `<a onclick='"\' apóstrofo - \" aspa"'></a>`. Ou:

```
"\x22" // aspa (ASCII)
String.fromCharCode(0x22) // aspa
String.fromCharCode(34) // aspa
"\x27" // apóstrofo (ASCII)
"\u0022" // aspa (UTF-8)
"\u0027" // apóstrofo (UTF-8)
```

---

Exemplo fundamental do uso da tag `<script/>`.

```
<script>
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function() {
    exibirVideo('\
                Embed code')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Olá @nicematt, Obrigado pela resposta, é que na mesma página eu terei várias embeds que só seriam carregadas (na verdade eu uso php para adquirir essas embeds de um banco de dados e faço uma manipulação para passar também na função exibir vídeo o id da div onde usarei document.innerHTML), eu resolvi esse problema criando um <input type="hidden" value="embed_code"> com um id e o valor desse input seria a string em php da embed usando o htmlentities() função do php

Comment: Vou deixar aqui um embed de um vídeo que peguei no vimeo para teste:
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/176377950?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

Comment: sem problemas, eu acredito que o problema que tava tendo antes se dava por conta do ">" no final, acabava fechando a anchor prematuramente

Comment: Peraí, você está colocando um código HTML dentro de um atributo, é isso? É possível escapar caracteres nesse código, mas se sua solução funcionou, está tudo bem, mas o problema está nas aspas. Eu ainda recomendaria usar a tag "script" para deixar o projeto mais organizado

Comment: infelizmente como o caso é muito específico, acredito que fique melhor da forma que fiz para esse caso, mas para outros a dica foi muito útil! Obrigado!